# Measure time in Java JNI ( native call Java)

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface, measure, elapsedtime

I am trying to measure time in JNI call, it call from native to Java.

In C code, I apply "GetTickCount" api to get JNI execution time and "System.nano" in Java.

Example:

```
long start = GetTickCount();
....//CallStaticMethod exampleMethod...
long end = GetTickCount();
long duration = end - start;
```

And in Java

```
public static exampleMethod(){
    long start = System.nano();
    //do something
    long end = System.nano();
    long duration = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMilis(end - start);
}
```

Sometimes, it is inconsistent because the java's duration is more than C's duration. ( about 5 to 10 miliseconds)

Comment: `GetTickCount` returns **milli**seconds, `System.nanoTime()` returns **nano**seconds.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. It's not related to unit time. I miss the last line code while I post here. Actually, I convert nano to miliseconds in my source code :). Java's duration is more than C's duration as the same unit ( miliseconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetTickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) use different time sources.

The problem with `GetTickCount` is its very poor resolution, usually around 10ms. This is explicitly remarked in the documentation:

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the
>   resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.

No wonder that it can differ from `nanoTime` that much.

To make measurements consistent with `System.nanoTime`, use higher resolution timer by calling either [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx).

**EDIT**

JDK's `System.nanoTime()` is implemented on top of `QueryPerformanceCounter` [(the source)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/0cd040567d60/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l853).

Comment: Thanks for your support. It's very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

On the java side of things you will always be at the mercy of the JVM :

http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/